# Enum conforming to Protocol for property which has a getter and setter

Tags: swift

Is there a limitation to Enums, I can not set a property of protocol implemented by Enum.

I want to make Headers field configurable, allow headers to set.
I know Enums have only computed properties, is this even possible.

```
protocol APIConfiguration : URLRequestConvertible {
    var method : HTTPMethod { get }
    var path : String { get }
    var parameters : Parameters? { get }
    var baseURL : String { get }
    var headers : [String : String]? { get set }
}

enum LoginEndpoint: APIConfiguration
{

    case login
    case user


    // MARK: - Base URL
    var baseURL : String
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .login, .user:
            return K.Graph.baseURI
        }
    }


    // MARK: - HTTPMethod
    var method : HTTPMethod
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .login:
            return .get
        case .user:
            return .get
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Path
    var path : String
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .login:
            return "/v1.0/me/"
        case .user:
            return "/user.read"
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Parameters
    var parameters : Parameters?
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .login:
            return nil
        case .user:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var headers : [String : String]?
    {
        get {
            if let sessionToken = SessionStore.shared.sessionToken
            {
                return [HTTPHeaderField.authentication.rawValue:sessionToken]
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {}
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the `set` portion of your `headers` computed property in your `LoginEndpoint` enum?

Comment: I know this was gonna come if I set a header it will get tap into the recursive call. Also edited the code above

Comment: Why doesn't your `headers` computed property set anything? Shouldn't it set the provided values  somewhere?

Comment: If I set the headers like set { headers = newValue }, this will get trapped in the recursive call. I cannot create a stored property as it is Enum and assign the newValue to that property.

Comment: It's a computed property. The `set`needs to apply the newValue to the `HTTPHeaderField` or something similar to what the `get` does.

Comment: Yes as it is a computed property, I cannot set itself, get is just returning the singleton sessionToken that I created to overcome the limitation here.

Comment: `LoginEndpoint` really isn't a good use case for an `enum`. The definitions of your login endpoints are fractured between 5 different computed properties, and it's really clunky. It would be better for `APIConfiguration` to be a simple struct, with `login` and `user` being stored static properties with populated values